# Date format with Spring Boot don`t work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I Put in my `aplication.properties`:

```
spring.jackson.date-format=dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss
```

And in my `Application.java`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ComponentScan
@EnableWebMvc
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer
{
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }


}
```

Then I create one method to return one `Date`:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/teste/")
public Date teste() {
    return new Date();
}
```

So when I call this method I got this return:

> 1466081600310

and not the

> 16/06/2016 10:00:00 (today)

this happen with another field in my objects.

Comment: How is your controller annotated? Also your `Application` doesn't need all those annotations. remove all of them except `@SpringBootApplication` and relaunch... (Actually `@EnableWebMvc` might be the fact that your formatting isn't working).

Comment: After I remove the @EnableMvc  the method that return only one Date works, but the Date inside my objects dont :(

Comment: spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS=false

Comment: Don`t work.. the problem are when the springboot get the date 2016-06-16 (example) he convert to one java.util.Date and convert to 2016-06-16 (-3 hours) so instead to conver to 2016-06-16 00:00:00 he converts to 2016-06-15 21:00:00

Answer (score 1):

Hope you already found the reason.

I'm using Spring Boot 2.1.3, and encountered similar issue as well. Then I found this po:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6642

which indicates the cause might be "@EnableWebMvc".

Hope it could help.